# CSS + JS – Push body right when sidenav opens without resizing images

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm attempting to push the entire body of my page right when I click on my hamburger menu, but when I do so, my images resize, along with everything that is set to `margin: 0 auto;` causing those elements to stray to the middle of the view. Is there a work around where I can push all of the contents of my page to the right, making them spill out of the view rather than resizing? Would love to stay away from jQuery and just do this with Vanilla JS.

BEFORE:
[image]

AFTER:
[image]

My CSS:

```
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1c2234;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f5d0cd;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
}
.hero-container {
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("hero.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<body>
    <!-- Sidenav -->
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Visit</a>
      <a href="#">Catering</a>
      <a href="#">Wholesale</a>
      <a href="#">Shop</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Main separates main content from side nav -->
    <div id="main">
      <!-- Header -->
      <header>
        <nav>
          <div class="row">
            <ion-icon name="menu" id="hamburger" onclick="openNav()"></ion-icon>
            <%= link_to image_tag("blue_filled_mark1.png", :alt => "Valor Logo", :id => "main-logo"), root_path %>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>

      <section class="hero-container">
        <div class="hero">
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
 </body>
```

My Javascript:

```
function openNav() { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you increase the left margin of your `#main` container, you are actually decreasing it's available width to render it's children. Instead, you can use `position: relative; left: 250px` to "push" the `#main` div off to the right without changing its width:

```js
function openNav() { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.left = "250px";
}

function closeNav() { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.left = "0";
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1c2234;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f5d0cd;
}

#main {
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
.hero-container {
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://us.123rf.com/450wm/stockbroker/stockbroker1506/stockbroker150603180/42131668-family-buying-fresh-vegetables-at-farmers-market-stall.jpg?ver=6");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.row {
  background: #222;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 15px;
}

.row span {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row span:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!-- Sidenav -->
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Visit</a>
      <a href="#">Catering</a>
      <a href="#">Wholesale</a>
      <a href="#">Shop</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Main separates main content from side nav -->
    <div id="main">
      <!-- Header -->
      <header>
        <nav>
          <div class="row">
            <span name="menu" id="hamburger" onclick="openNav()">Open Menu</span>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>

      <section class="hero-container">
        <div class="hero">
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `background-size: auto 100%` on `.hero`:

```js
function openNav() { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1c2234;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f5d0cd;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
}

.hero-container {
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://cdn-image.departures.com/sites/default/files/styles/responsive_900x600/public/take-me-to-madison-avenue_2000x1333.jpg?itok=gN5iGEtX");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- Sidenav -->
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Visit</a>
    <a href="#">Catering</a>
    <a href="#">Wholesale</a>
    <a href="#">Shop</a>
  </div>
  <!-- Main separates main content from side nav -->
  <div id="main">
    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div class="row">
          <b name="menu" id="hamburger" onclick="openNav()">menu</b>
          
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <section class="hero-container">
      <div class="hero">
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
Change the .hero background size to '100vw', rather than 100%.

```
.hero {
   height: 100vh;
   background-image: url("hero.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100vw;
}
```

**Option 2:** Set the width of #main to '100vw'

```
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  width: 100vw
}
```

Adding the margin-left reduces the width of #main, because it's not explicitly set. Because using percentages to size the background is relative to the parent container, the background image shrinks to fit the new size of #main. The 'vw' unit is essentially the same thing, except it is relative to the viewport vs. the parent element. ([See a good explanation of VW here](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units?utm_source=feedburner)).  Setting the background to a fixed size (Option 1) forces the width to stay 100% of the viewport, even when the parent shrinks. Setting the parent element (#main) to a fixed size (Option 2) also works.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

here's an idea:

html:

```
<body>
  <div class="body-wrap">
    <!-- Sidenav -->
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Visit</a>
      <a href="#">Catering</a>
      <a href="#">Wholesale</a>
      <a href="#">Shop</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Main separates main content from side nav -->
    <div id="main">
      <!-- Header -->
      <header>
        <nav>
          <div class="row">
            <ion-icon name="menu" id="hamburger" onclick="openNav()"></ion-icon>
            <%= link_to image_tag("blue_filled_mark1.png", :alt => "Valor Logo", :id => "main-logo"), root_path %>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>

      <section class="hero-container">
        <div class="hero">
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

css:

```
.sidenav{
  width: 200px; /*or whatever width you want*/
  left: -200px;
  position: fixed;
}

.sidenav.open{
  left: 0;
}

.body-wrap {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.body-wrap.open {
  left: 200px;
}
```

then on your click event just toggle your open class on and off.